# How to replace a particular value only in a list

Tags: java, list, hibernate

The following method uses hibernate query to take a table into the list called `prefixApplyList` Now i want to do decryption on a particular attribute called `prefix` only before returning that list. How can i call that decryption method for that attribute `prefix` which is present inside that list

```
    public List getPrefixMasterList() {
    if (prefixMasterList == null) {
        prefixMasterList = getBaseAppService().find("PrefixMaster.list");
    }
    return prefixMasterList;
   }
```

Comment: You can iterate on list and check the property of that list and decrypt it.

Comment: I have added the screenshot. Now can you explain how to do that.

Comment: Try something like **for(PrefixMaster l : prefixMasterList){ l.setPrefix(decrypt(l.getPrefix()));}**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Its working fine when i used iterator. Hope it will help someone.

```
Iterator itr = prefixMasterList.iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext()){
            PrefixMaster pm = (PrefixMaster) itr.next();
            pm.setPrefix(decrypt(pm.getPrefix()));
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through the `prefixMasterList` before the `return` statement and you will get elements one by one.

Get element and decrypt it.

```
for(PrefixMaster pm : prefixMasterList){
    pm.setPrefix(decryptMethod(pm.getPrefix()));
}
```

Comment: prefixMasterList shows an error called Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to PrefixMaster

Comment: Are you sure prefixMasterList is List<PrefixMaster> ? if yes then mismatch should not happen and if no then try to change it to List<PrefixMaster>

Comment: outside loop try this List<PrefixMaster> prefixMasters = (List<PrefixMaster>)prefixMasterList;  and then iterate prefixMasters .

Comment: Now i used the encryption and decryption for the PrefixMasterBean only. There are number of other masters also. So instead of using encryption and decryption method inside every bean is there any other easy way for doing that. Something like generic

Comment: I mean is there any way to do that? @Alien